# Algorithm for calculating amount of won games in last 10 games

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql

There are tables in database:

```
Game table with columns:
id
scoreA smallint
scoreB smallint
teamidA integer
teamidB integer
day smallint
time_of_start timestamp 

and Team table 
id
l10Stat smallint
```

Explanation for the Game table:
after game is finished that table is updated so that scores are filled for teamA and teamB.
day is the day number of the season (from 1 till 28)
the time_of_start is a time of start of the game on that day (from 00:00 to 24:00)

Also for each team the l10Stat should be filled.
l10Stat is a statistics showing how many games that team won in last 10 games.

I could do the query like:

```
SELECT ... FROM Game Where (day_number < :current_day time < :current_time) order by day, current_day desc
```

But thats very not optimal. It gonna be slow because there are a lots of games.
I want to find the way to solve this task by making simple fast query. 
May be there will be a need to put additional columns or tables. 
Could you help with the best way to solve this task?

**EDIT1:**
TeamA won the game if ScoreA > ScoreB (same with TeamB)

Comment: It's gonna be slow or it is slow? Post `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the following query to make it suit your needs but the idea is clear, you have to ROW_NUMBER() so you can easily filter the games.

```
    SELECT lg.teamidA, SUM(lg.Won) AS Wins FROM (
        SELECT 
          teamidA
        , CASE WHEN scoreA > scoreB THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Won
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY teamidA ORDER BY day_number DESC, time_of_start DESC) AS Rn
        FROM Game) AS lg
        WHERE rn <= 10
        GROUP BY teamidA
UNION ALL 
    SELECT lg.teamidB, SUM(lg.Won) AS Wins FROM (
        SELECT 
          teamidA
        , CASE WHEN scoreB > scoreA THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Won
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY teamidB ORDER BY day_number DESC, time_of_start DESC) AS Rn
        FROM Game) AS lg
        WHERE rn <= 10
        GROUP BY teamidB
```